# How to add forked github repo to package.json

Tags: npm, next.js, package.json

I'm building website using NextJS. I'm looking for draggable tree component and I found interesting one but to support some features, I would need to edit source code. Should I simply clone the entire repo for that component and put it in my project? But then I'm afraid I will no be able to pull new updates from original repo. What is the recommended way to do that?

Comment: Are the features you need specific for you? Can't you just extend the draggable tree component inside your own js file and add the features to your liking? You can then keep up with the updates of the package and don't have to fork the repo.